# Python glob - differentiate between similar filenames in different directories

Tags: python, excel, file, glob, pathlib

I'm using glob recursively to find all excel files in directory, including files located in sub directories. After that, I stem the whole path of the file and only put the excel name on a list for later usage. However, the problem I'm having is when I encounter 2 different excel files but with similar name.
I want the ability to differentiate between them on my stemmed list.
For example: This what happens now with 3 files in the directory, 2 of which bearing the same name:

```
mainDirectory/subDirectory1/file1.xlsx
mainDirectory/subDirectory2/file1.xlsx
mainDirectory/subDirectory2/file2.xlsx
```

The list would be:

```
file1
file2
file1
```

And it creates a lot of problems for me afterwards, so I need help on how to add something for each 2 files to make them unique, and later on to remove it.
I'm thinking maybe to add the parent sub directory up, something like this:

```
subDirectory1/file1
file2
subDirectory2/file1
```

Is there an option in glob to deal with this issue? Or anything else?
Here is my code:

```
    excel_list = []
    file_list = []
    f = []
    file_list = glob.glob(path + "/**" + "/*.xlsx", recursive=True)
    f.extend(file_list)
    for x in f:
        x = pathlib.Path(x).stem
        excel_list.append(x)
```

Comment: Can you keep both the stemmed and the full versions? It's hard to recommend something without knowing what you do with the list afterwards...

Comment: Why don't you just put the entire pathname in your list? If you only have the stem (basename) how would you ever know where that file came from in subsequent processing?

Comment: I’m using the stemmed list on a GUi with tkinter, and I want it to be user friendly so I stemmed the excel names. After that, whenever the user chooses the excels he wants, I iterate through the original file list and if the stemmed file is contained within- I add it to a list

Comment: Are elads11 and 123josh123 one and the same? Or has stack**overflow** had an aberration?

Comment: Right, you need to keep track of the full pathname, but only show an abbreviated version in the UI?

Comment: Yes, exactly keeping track but showing only abbreviated version on ui

Comment: What widget are you using for that?

Comment: I guess you still want to show different text if there are multiple files called "file1", otherwise the user will be quite confused...

Comment: So there would be two separate problems (a) how to take a list of files and reduce them to a stemmed list while keeping enough to disambiguate everything; and (b) how to map it back afterwards. For (b), either the widget has a facility for attaching additional information, or you can keep the mapping in a dictionary. For (a), you'll need to design a more complicated algorithm...

Comment: One option would be to use the standard "directory tree" style widget, limited to just the directories that contain the Excel files; that would probably be both easier to implement and less confusing for users than most alternatives

Comment: The widget is a listbox, with option to choose one, or more including a button to select everything. But what I have in my mind is to make each file unique on the UI , so the user can know from which sub directory, the file came from